# How to parse file with square brackets?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, brackets

I have a data file like this :

```
[TOP]
Name=                 1
Plic=                 11
Glab=                 5487
Gendr=                2261
Mars=                 0
[ENDTOP]
[TOP]
Name=                 2
Plic=                 13
Glab=                 5556
Gendr=                2321
Mars=                 E
[ENDTOP]
[TOP]
Name=                 2
Plic=                 55
Glab=                 4012
Gendr=                3758
Mars=                 2
[ENDTOP]
```

I need to parse it with python3 to a csv file with header :

```
Name;Plic;Glab;Gendr;Mars
1;11;5487;2261;0
2;13;5556;2321;E
2;55;4012;3758;2
```

But I'm stuck with it; I tried with dict but it only keeps the last keys :

```
for line in f.readlines():
        line = ligne.split('=')
        if len(line) == 2:
            table[line[0].strip()]= line[1].strip()
```

Can someone help me to achieve it?

Comment: This almost looks like an INI file. With some small changes to its format (so it has no duplicated sections/keys, for example have a single `name` key with comma-separated values, or have unique sections names like `[section1]...[section2]`) you can use standard lib [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module

Comment: Anyway, `dict` only store one value per key. If you want multiple values you need to use lists as the values, then append

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple file format. This code parses the file into an list of dictionaries. It should be easy to save to a csv from there.

```
all_data = []
for line in f.readlines():
    if line.strip() == "[TOP]":
        # Start - create empty dictionary
        line_data = {}
    elif line.strip() == "[ENDTOP]":
        # End - save dictionary to list
        all_data.append(line_data)
    else:
        # Data - save to dictionary
        data = line.split('=')
        if len(data) == 2:
            line_data[data[0]] = data[1].strip()
```

Produces:

```
[
{'Name': '1', 'Plic': '11', 'Glab': '5487', 'Gendr': '2261', 'Mars': '0'},
{'Name': '2', 'Plic': '13', 'Glab': '5556', 'Gendr': '2321', 'Mars': 'E'},
{'Name': '2', 'Plic': '55', 'Glab': '4012', 'Gendr': '3758', 'Mars': '2'}
]
```